# Android Studio: Clone Failed! Failed to Start Git process

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I Started New Android Project with my Friend.

He does some work and uploaded on Git.

I used Android Studio[v2.3.3] and when i clone repository it Show message Like

Clone Failed!
Failed to Start Git Process!

Comment: Try to clone using command line.

Comment: Did it. still not working!

Comment: Then the problem probably has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: Do you have Git installed?

Comment: check this http://www.geekshangout.com/android-studio-clone-failed-failed-to-start-git-process/.

Comment: @ MohammedFarhan  Yes i have installed Git. and I already Google this Problem, not worth it! So I asked on Stack. @paril this [Link](http://www.geekshangout.com/android-studio-clone-failed-failed-to-start-git-process/ ) is not what i want. I can Google this already.

Comment: Perhaps your system (Bash or whatever) does not know git? Try `git init` in some folder.

Comment: I solved the Error. With the help of GIT Terminal [Oh My Zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/). I don't know but problem resolved. and good job @ohmyzsh

Comment: Voted to close as abandoned and user says fixed but "I don't know but problem resolved" and user is now long gone.

Comment: So this question will be of no use to anyone else and just confusing

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Git. Check this [download link](https://git-scm.com/downloads) & choose your operating system.

Once the installation is done go to Android Studio settings & look for version control. Then add the path of Git.

Comment: Are you certain this is the solution?

Comment: I remember fixing this issue with the above steps. But, generally this kind of issues may have several causes. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just delete intellij-git-askpass and intellij-ssh-askpass in the Android studio4.0 >ststem> tmp
Then repeat the cloning, it worked for me